# Survey lacks a back button

Tags: bug, survey, survey-2017

**Steps to reproduce:** Start taking the developer survey. Part way through, realise you made a mistake on an earlier page

**Expected result:** Able to click a Back button to return to an earlier page to correct the mistake

**Actual result:** Have to either submit incorrect information, or restart the survey (using an incognito window, because, reasons?). Clicking the browser Back button takes you to your browser's "confirm form resubmission page"; resubmitting takes you to *the page you were trying to go back **from***.

Comment: I'd not call that a bug. It is, at best, a missing feature.

Comment: Doesn't your browser provide a back button? Why would webpages need to duplicate features of the browser?

Comment: @CodyGray: The browser back button makes the survey freak out (crash)

Comment: Wow. Is this the first time they've used Survey Monkey? What a disaster. Judging by Meta, I'm not looking forward to taking this thing myself.

Comment: I filled in a question wrong, pressed back, and will now have to start over :-( Not impressed.

Comment: * Calls everything a bug * - Just user things...

Comment: @MartijnPieters I suspect that styling this as a bug report was a way of emphasising what an elementary feature a back button is.

Answer (score -22, accepted):

**Edit:**
Thanks for your feedback, everyone, especially the specific reports of the types of mistakes you've been making, and pointing out that people have been trying to get around this by straight out re-taking the survey.

Considering this further evidence, we ran a test over the last few days, assessing whether:

1. Allowing respondents to move back through the survey affects the distribution of responses on certain key questions that we are treating as dependent variables for analysis (e.g. overall career satisfaction), and
2. Whether allowing respondents to move back affected the distribution of responses to the "used/want" question about programming languages, including the  proportion of respondents who chose both "used in the last year" and "want to use in the next year" for at least one language.  We chose this question as a proxy for overall response quality because it is long, relatively complicated, and will be a key "report out" question when the results are published.

Regarding #1, we found no significant differences, which indicates that our concern about measurement of independent variables impacting the measurement of dependent variables isn't playing out on the ground.  We also found no significant differences regarding #2, which indicates that the overall survey error introduced by the lack of a back button is low.

Given those results, and the feedback we've received here, we've decided to enable moving back.  New respondents will be able to edit their responses whilst taking the survey, but will not be able to further edit responses once they click "done" at the end.  Respondents who took the survey while the "prev" button was turned off will be able to edit their responses if the following are both true:

1. You still have a record of which link you accessed the survey from in your browser history.
2. SurveyMonkey recognizes you.

In that case, you will "land" on the last page of the survey and find you are able to "prev" back through it.  We will keep this editing capability available through the end of January.

If those conditions do not apply to you (e.g. you were in incognito mode when you took the survey), I'm afraid we don't have a solution for editing your original results at this time.  If that's an issue for you, please let me know in the comments here, and we'll try to work the problem.

**Original answer:**
I'm sorry you had a frustrating experience.  That said, this is a feature, not a bug, and we will not be activating a "back" button.

Why?  There are three key reasons:

First, we want responses to be candid, and for respondents to not over-think things.  The philosophy here is "first thought, best thought."

Second, we want to be able to control for ordering effects.  I.e. if being exposed to question #2 makes you re-consider your answer to question #1, so you go back and change your answers, then your response to #1 has been biased.

Finally -- and this goes for any survey, but especially one where developers are the audience -- we don't want to encourage any reverse-engineering of the survey logic, with people trying to open question paths that they had skipped previously or anything like that.  (Anyone who's interested in that will be able to see the full instrument when we publish it, after the field period closes.)

The downside to this approach is there are cases where people make mistakes due to (among other things) not reading the questions carefully, mis-tapping on a mobile screen, etc.  If that's what happened to you, again, I'm sorry for any frustration.

Comment: I understand the desire to have candid responses, but I think it would be more valuable to not keep bad data when the individual knows that they made a mistake and would like to give you correct data.

Comment: "if being exposed to question #2 makes you re-consider your answer to question #1" -- then question #1 probably wasn't very clear.

Comment: Also, if you're trying to *prevent* people from being able to change their answers, why are you tracking the user's progress in some kind of transient browser data instead of associating it with their account? (As some users have noted, you can circumvent the restriction by using an incognito window, and when I tried to return to the quiz after waiting a day or so I was surprised to find myself at the beginning again even though I think I was using the same browser.)

Comment: When I read this answer the first time I assumed it was satire. Did not like reading it a second time under updated assumptions.

Comment: I ***never*** complete surveys if I need to backtrack and cannot do so. You need to rethink this policy. You also need to rethink whether a mistake is merely 'candid' and whether it really constitutes a 'best thought'.

Comment: `we want responses to be candid, and for respondents to not over-think things. The philosophy here is "first thought, best thought."`, `if being exposed to question #2 makes you re-consider your answer to question #1, so you go back and change your answers, then your response to #1 has been biased.` -> Frankly, this is just ... mindblowing. Real honesty – not phony honesty – comes with introspection, thinking things over, and – occasionally – **changing your mind**.

Comment: One can reverse engineer the survey anyway. There's absolutely nothing (except for a cookie) stopping you from taking the survey multiple times.

Comment: I took the survey, made mistakes on it, was annoyed by the lack of back button, and trudged on through. If this is the way of things going forward however, I will not be taking the survey next year.  If I don't have the opportunity to correct my answers then I'm taking the time to do a job which I can only do half-assed ... and I don't like doing that at all, so I will spend my time elsewhere.

Comment: Whoever was in charge of the survey this year really has blown it. This is embarrassing. I've taken it every year since it was introduced, but I don't think I'll be taking it this year. I'll be encouraging others to abstain as well, until you guys can get your act together.

Comment: But @CodyGray! The badge! What about the badge?!

Comment: @Thunderforge No researcher ever wants data to be bad.  But since no dataset is every perfect, making one the least-bad it can be comes down to a lot of tradeoffs.  It would be helpful if you (and other folks here) could tell me what sort of mistakes you were trying to correct when you wanted to go back to a previous Q.  There may be other remedies we can institute.  Or it may be that, come Monday morning, I consult with the team and we decide that our estimation of the probability of someone making a mistake that they should be able to correct has changed.

Comment: @KyleStrand re: questions being clear, by all means, let us know if there was something unclear that made you want to go back to a previous Q, or (for that matter) any UI problems that forced you onto a "bad path" through the survey. That said, here's an example of the type of revisions we don't want. Someone rates his current job satisfaction a 10. Then he sees the "how often do you work remotely?" question, and says to himself, "wow, come to think of it, I wish I could do that," so he goes back and changes his rating.  Take a look at [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker see my comments to Kyle and Thunderforge above.  If you change your mind about (say) current job satisfaction, or the importance to you of compensation & benefits when looking at a job offer, or your satisfaction with Stack Overflow, during the 30 minutes you're taking the survey, it's very likely you changed your mind because you were exposed to stimuli that primed you to make that change.  It would be helpful to hear what sort of corrections you were trying to make on the survey when you wanted to go back.

Comment: @KevinTroy I see your point, but that's not actually an example of psychological priming (which is a subconscious effect and is not, as far as I can tell, among the very few results in psychology that aren't being challenged now due to the replication crisis). If someone has new information and it changes their mind on a particular matter--in your example, if someone is really *perfectly satisfied* with their job until they realize that some people can work from home--then it's unclear to me what the benefit is of trying to measure the community's "pre-survey" attitudes.

Comment: The reasons that people are wanting a back button are [misunderstanding the question and not realizing it until the next page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341548/531762), [choosing a branching question but then running into a bug](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/The-2017-Stack-Overflow-Developer-Survey-is-Now-Live/?cb=1#comment-3097698382), [personal principles](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341469/survey-lacks-a-back-button/341550#comment432639_341550), and for me: accidentally pressing the Next button on an optional question while scrolling on mobile.

Comment: I could also see people wanting to go back if they accidentally picked the wrong choice on an earlier answer and the current question is meaningless (e.g. I meant to pick United States, didn't realize I picked United Kingdom until it asked me if I was in England, Wales, etc). It's worth noting that several people are [recommending retaking the exam in Incognito mode](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/The-2017-Stack-Overflow-Developer-Survey-is-Now-Live/?cb=1#comment-3098073919) in order to get around the lack of a back button, which I think is more damaging than any priming effects.

Comment: @KevinTroy I wished for a back button when I realised that there was indeed a framework I would have liked to add to the list.

Comment: @JonasWielicki thanks, that's helpful

Comment: @Thunderforge thanks.  Yes, re-taking is a concern.

Comment: I'm going to 'accept' this answer as word of god, but please, next time, if you will only accept our 'first thoughts', **tell us up-front that that is the protocol in place**, and we will think long and hard before each click of Next!

Comment: There were at least three questions where I read the answers too fast (this was last week, so I don't remember exactly which ones), clicked the one I thought was best, then just before the list changed, I saw an answer that was more accurate/a better fit. And I had wanted, half-way through, to return to the education question because I wasn't fully comfortable with my answer and wanted to see if there was a better answer. (I have an associates degree, and I did not enjoy the "Some college" answer I had to click for that.) I finished the survey, but I was much less happy than last year...

Comment: The new answer would probably be worth adding as a separate one, as it's vastly different from the original one and it's very confusing to see the vote count

Comment: Reversing my vote as this is...really quite a fantastic example of listening to the community, testing your prior assumptions, updating your opinions, and quickly acting to rectify the situation. Thanks to you and anyone else involved on the SO side. I had previously given up partway through the survey (and hoped that maybe you'd track how many respondents did that), but now I'll definitely finish it!

Comment: ....although I do seem to have lost my former progress. Not sure if that's due to the change in the UI mechanics of the survey, or because I lost my cached browser data, or what.

Comment: Thanks for reconsidering and taking the time to get some data on this. As we say in Dutch: "meten in weten" ("measuring is knowing").