# "Worked with last year and want to work with in the future" question leading to bad data

Tags: discussion, survey-2017

When doing the survey I came across a question that asked what programming languages you are currently using and what languages you would like to continue working with in the future. I incorrectly assumed that the check boxes where either or and hit next. I immediately realized my mistake, but due to a lack of a back button could not correct it.

Reading the comments on this page: http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/The-2017-Stack-Overflow-Developer-Survey-is-Now-Live/?cb=1

It seems like many people had the exact same problem. I feel like this question is going to have completely misguided data. The languages that people work with may be deemed more unpopular then the ones that people want to work with.

Thoughts?

Comment: People reported the same issue with this question on the blog [here](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/The-2017-Stack-Overflow-Developer-Survey-is-Now-Live/?cb=1#comment-3097839438) and [here](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/The-2017-Stack-Overflow-Developer-Survey-is-Now-Live/?cb=1#comment-3096767208).

Comment: Interesting, I guess I've got too much of a programmer mindset since I didn't see any ambiguity there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out here.  I also saw the blog post, and plan to respond there as soon as I'm able.

We're making a few tweaks to the survey, which we'll be pushing out on Monday, and plan to add a clarification to the prompts for these questions.

Comment: What happens after you add clarifications? Do you only use data from that point onwards when looking at results for those questions?

Comment: @JKillian we're going to look carefully at things like "% of respondents who checked both rows for at least one language" before and after changing the prompt before we make a determination.